# Assetic css images have disappeared

Tags: php, symfony, yui-compressor

I have this image: Symfony/web/bundles/BackendBundle/images/main.png

I enable yui compresor for this style: Symfony/web/bundles/BackendBundle/images/main.css, it orks fine.

I have this in config.yml: cssrewrite: ~

But images of main.css does not work, why?

I try this different formats:

```
background-image: url(/bundles/BackendBundle/images/main.png);
background-image: url(bundles/BackendBundle/images/main.png);
background-image: url(../images/main.png);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution, I reply my question:
{% stylesheets "bundles/BackendBundle/css/*" filter="**cssrewrite,** yui_css" %}
I put cssrewrite in assetic declaration and relative path works

Answer (score 0):

The CSS File is in the same directory as the images, you would simply call:

```
background-image: url('main.png');
```

Also, you didn't list above that "main_bg2.png" is uploaded, only main.png. You may be missing the files you are trying to call with CSS - upload them if you haven't. Sometimes with multiple extensions of the same file name, things get confusing.

Comment: sorry the answer is bad, is nor main_bd2.png :p

Comment: Care to elaborate on your question or comment?